# Trailing whitespace in varchar needs to be considered in comparison

Tags: mysql

I am using a table with a varchar column.  I did not realize that trailing whitespace is not considered in comparisons (and that, apparently, two values that differ only in amount of trailing whitespace will violate the uniqueness property, if specified).

I need to fix this in the table, preferably in place.  Is there a recommended path to fixing a table like this in MySQL?

I am accessing the DB strictly through a program I control, so switching to a non-human readable format such as binary would be fine.  But I am not sure how to do such a thing and don't want to destroy the table.

Comment: Interesting problem.  The workaround that comes to mind is to append some character to the end of all the values, and then strip it off when you read the value out of the table.

Comment: If your issue has been solved, please choose an accepted answer, or submit your own solution.

Answer (score 12):

I have to assume you're using MySQL 5.x because MySQL 4.x doesn't store trailing spaces in a VARCHAR column.

Using the standard `=` operator in MySQL, as you indicated, trailing spaces are not considered:

`SELECT 'this' = 'this '` returns TRUE

However, [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html) compares the strings character by character, so trailing spaces are significant.

`SELECT 'this' LIKE 'this '` returns FALSE.

Both `=` and `LIKE` may be case insensitive, using the default collation. Use the [`COLLATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) clause to specify the collation if you need to compare them in a case sensitive manner.

Comment: Using LIKE instead of `=` opens a can of worms, for example when comparing against strings coming from the user input.

Answer (score 2):

Could you run on empty query on  the table field  that has the whitespace?

```
RTRIM(str)
```

> Returns the string str with trailing
>   space characters removed.  mysql>
>   SELECT RTRIM('barbar   ');
>           -> 'barbar' This function is multi-byte safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is ancient, but you can also use the `binary` keyword.

```
mysql> select 'hello'='hello  ', binary 'hello'='hello  ';
+-------------------+--------------------------+
| 'hello'='hello  ' | binary 'hello'='hello  ' |
+-------------------+--------------------------+
|                 1 |                        0 |
+-------------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This will also make the search case sensitive.

```
mysql> select 'hello'='HELLO', binary 'hello'='HELLO';
+-----------------+------------------------+
| 'hello'='HELLO' | binary 'hello'='HELLO' |
+-----------------+------------------------+
|               1 |                      0 |
+-----------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Database collation has a significant role in this. I had a similar situation and figured out that character set = utf8mb4 and collation = utf8mb4_0900_as_cs solves this problem.

You can read more [here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL as well as MariaDB there is such a thing as COLLATE. This defines how equality on strings should be handled. You can choose to have case sensitivity or not, depending on if you want "Foo" to be equal to "FOO" or not. Since MariaDB 10.2, you can also specify if you want trailing spaces to be ignored or not.

Sources: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-collations-table/