# MySQL 5.5 losing trailing spaces in query

Tags: mysql

I am building a database in which trailing space is important to the results.  When I query for a result I find that

```
SELECT * where `field` = 'a '
```

Returns a result when there is a field who's value is 'a'.  I want the trailing space to matter in the result set.  I have tried using Char, Varchar, Text, and Blob. I will note that this field is the index of my table.

Can someone show me how to query in a way that makes trailing (and/or leading) spaces count? Do I need to format my table in any special way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is by design, not only in MySQL.

You can work around it in *comparisons* by using `BINARY`:

```
mysql> select version(), 'a' = 'a ', BINARY 'a' = BINARY 'a ';
+-------------+------------+--------------------------+
| version()   | 'a' = 'a ' | BINARY 'a' = BINARY 'a ' |
+-------------+------------+--------------------------+
| 5.5.25a-log |          1 |                        0 |
+-------------+------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but not much more. This will help you with `SELECT`s if whitespaces appear e.g. in user input to a search; but if you want to actually input whitespace-trailed information, it will be a problem (you can't have an index with both 'a' and 'a ').

See also

[Trailing whitespace in varchar needs to be considered in comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668996/trailing-whitespace-in-varchar-needs-to-be-considered-in-comparison)

You could conceivably *reverse* the strings in that column, and reverse them back when displaying them. Of course this will wreck any ordering based on that column, but if you only test equality or substring existence, it just might work. *Leading* spaces do count.

For equality searches you might also store the base64 encoding of the string, which ought to maintain the lexicographical order (i.e., the order between a and b ought to be maintained between base64(a) and base64(b)). Or you might append a terminator on the string ("\n" could do well and not appear in searches).

Finally, but it's risky because humans can't tell the difference, you could replace spaces with the UTF8 char(49824):

```
mysql> select concat ('\'a', char(49824),'\'') AS tricked,
              concat ('\'a', ' '        ,'\'') as honest,
              concat ('\'a', char(49824),'\'') =
              concat ('\'a', ' '        ,'\'') as equals;

+---------+--------+--------+
| tricked | honest | equals |
+---------+--------+--------+
| 'a '    | 'a '   |      0 |
+---------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The rows *seem* to be equal, but they are not. Note that in HTML the space is a space, and 49824 is `&nbsp;` (nonbreaking space). This affects functions that convert to and fro HTML, and the nbsp being actually an UTF8 codepoint means that *honest* string is two bytes, but length of *tricked* string is actually *three*.

Finally you can declare the column `VARBINARY` instead of `VARCHAR`, thus completely hiding what's happening. It looks like the easiest solution, but I fear it might bite you some weeks or months down the line.

Comment: I realize that under most circumstances a db would want to remove leading and trailing spaces, but in my case they are important. In my case '  ' (2 spaces) and '   ' (3 spaces) are valid inputs and I need to distinguish between them, they are how I would search the table.  So based on this information any of the SQL langugaes may not be a solution?  Is there any way to accomplish what i'm looking for? I'm not locked into mySQL.  Unfortunatly my inputs can have leaing AND trailing spaces.

Comment: 'Many such hacks are possible'... I have listed a few. None is scot- or risk-free, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the information I may use base64 encoding I completely forgot about that I haven't used it in quite some time.  Thank you I'll see if that works.

Comment: The advantage of that approach (I'm a voodoo programmer :-( ) is that it makes very apparent that there's a bad karma connected with that column. And that avoids troubles down the line.

Comment: I added another possibility (I never really used that one, so it was slow in coming to mind). Use with caution :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have had success doing the following, but I'm not sure if it is an unstable approach.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  val VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
(NULL, 'a'),
(NULL, 'a '),
(NULL, 'a  '),
(NULL, 'a   ');

SELECT * FROM test
WHERE val LIKE 'a ';
```

Output

```
id  val
2   'a '
```

Using WHERE val = 'a ' will select all entries without taking trailing spaces into consideration, but LIKE works for me.

Comment: It does work; but then it's faster to use `SELECT * FROM test WHERE val = BINARY 'a ';` (`LIKE` is a tad slower). The big problem in OP's approach is maintainability. It's easy to forget that some columns are padded. And the main problem (the field being a primary key) isn't solved either way. In other circumstances yours is a quick fix though; +1 for that.