# MySQL trims value in WHERE

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, trim

I didn't find a similar question maybe because I don't find the correct words (English is not my first language)

## Problem

I have a `varchar` value that has a blank space at the end: `"opt-193-381-markets "` and when I do a `SELECT` with the value **without** the blank space, it returns the same result. It's like MySQL is trimming the value in the `WHERE`

Table definition:

```
mysql> desc message;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| FileId     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| MessageKey | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| NumericKey | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| IsObsolete | tinyint(4)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| notes      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Examples:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM message WHERE MessageKey = "opt-193-381-markets";
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| FileId | MessageKey           | NumericKey | IsObsolete | notes |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
|    304 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
|    337 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Notice that the `MessageKey` has the value with the blank space at the end and I just asked for the value without that blank space.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM message WHERE MessageKey = "opt-193-381-markets ";
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| FileId | MessageKey           | NumericKey | IsObsolete | notes |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
|    304 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
|    337 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Adding one more space

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM message WHERE MessageKey = "opt-193-381-markets  ";
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| FileId | MessageKey           | NumericKey | IsObsolete | notes |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
|    304 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
|    337 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

Escaping the spaces

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM message WHERE MessageKey = "opt-193-381-markets\ \ ";
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
| FileId | MessageKey           | NumericKey | IsObsolete | notes |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
|    304 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
|    337 | opt-193-381-markets  |          0 |          1 | NULL  |
+--------+----------------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

I've also tried with single quotes `'opt-193-381-markets'`

## Question

Why I cannot search for the exact value of `MessageKey`?

Thanks

Comment: try to use single qoutes instead of double quotes `'opt-193-381-markets '`

Comment: I've tried it, it's the same

Comment: So... now I will look into that.

Comment: Interesting, had never noticed this before.

Comment: What is the charset of this column / table?

Comment: and what version of MySQL is this?  There are a bunch of articles related to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542889/mysql-5-5-losing-trailing-spaces-in-query and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703349/mysql-disable-auto-trim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [binary comparison operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) .

`SELECT * FROM message WHERE BINARY(MessageKey) = 'opt-193-381-markets';`

Comment: Thank you!, This have worked. In minutes I'll give you the check